# How to expand application tabs

Tags: gnome, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8. GNOME desktop
How to expand bottom application tabs to present full name
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple solution: I moved the Trash icon to the right edge of the panel so now I have use of the full width of the bottom panel